# How to run a test in testNG using Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver**, **Java** and **TestNG** frame work.

Please give ideas about **TestNG** framework.

- For example, i have a file **test.java**. I have written java code with
  **@BeforeTest** , **@Test**, **@AfterTest**. while running the code each test is running and am getting how many test got passed and how many got failed.
- But i want solution for the secnario:
- I have two tabs called **Default** and **Internal vs External**

[image]

- After clicking the default tab i want run many test for that particular tab, once those test executed then i need to click on the Internal vs External then i need to run all test belongs to that tab.
- How can i get result in the TestNG frame work.

The following code:

```
public class OverviewAndEvolutionPR{
private static Logger Log = Logger.getLogger(OverviewAndEvolutionPR.class.getName());
private WebDriver driver;
private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();
Properties p= new Properties();
public Selenium selenium;
//@BeforeMethod
@BeforeTest
public void Login() throws Exception {
driver = new FirefoxDriver();
 try {
 p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Login.txt"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.getMessage();
 }
 String url=p.getProperty("url");
 DOMConfigurator.configure("src/log4j.xml");
 Log.info("______________________________________________________________");
 Log.info("Initializing Selenium...");
 selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox",url);
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 Log.info("Selenium instance started");
 try {
 p.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Login.txt"));
 } catch (Exception e) {
 e.getMessage();
 }
 Log.info("Accessing Stored uid,pwd from the stored text file");
 String uid=p.getProperty("loginUsername");
 String pwd=p.getProperty("loginPassword");
 Log.info("Retrieved uid pwd from the text file");
 try
 {
 driver.get("https://test.com");//example i had given like this
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
 Reporter.log("network server is slow..check internet connection");
 Log.info("Unable to open the website");
 throw new Error("network server is slow..check internet connection");
 }
 performLogin(uid,pwd);
 }  
 public void performLogin(String uid,String pwd) throws Exception  
 {
 Log.info("Sign in to the OneReports website");
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 Log.info("Enter Username");
 driver.findElement(By.id("loginUsername")).sendKeys(uid);
 Log.info("Enter Password");
 driver.findElement(By.id("loginPassword")).sendKeys(pwd); 
 //submit
 Log.info("Submitting login details");
 waitforElement(driver,120 , "//*[@id='submit']");
 driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).submit();
 Thread.sleep(6000);
 Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
 Log.info("Clicking on Reports link");
 if(existsElement("reports")==true){
 WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("reports"));
 actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
 Thread.sleep(6000);
 }
 else{
 Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
Log.info("Clicking on Extranet link");
if(existsElement("extranet")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("extranet"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
Log.info("Clicking on PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-pr")==true){
WebElement menuHoverLink = driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr"));
actions.moveToElement(menuHoverLink).perform();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{ 
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
Log.info("Clicking on Overview and Evolution PR link");
if(existsElement("ext-pr-backlog-evolution")==true){
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", driver.findElement(By.id("ext-pr-backlog-evolution") ));
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
else{
Log.info("element not present");
System.out.println("element not present -- so it entered the else loop");
}
}
//Filter selection-1
//This filter selection need to happen in Default tab
@Test()
public void Filterselection_1() throws Exception{
Log.info("Clicking on Visualization dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
  executor.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");
Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
select.selectByVisibleText("Week");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Period dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor1 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor1.executeScript("document.getElementById('periodId').style.display='block';");
Select select1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("periodId")));
select1.selectByVisibleText("Last 4 Weeks");
Thread.sleep(6000); 
Log.info("Clicking on Type dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor2 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor2.executeScript("document.getElementById('classificationId').style.display='block';");
Select select2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("classificationId")));
select2.selectByVisibleText("Customer PRs");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Apply Filter button");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
}
//In the default tab many filter section i will have once it completed then i need to move to other tab and need to check the filter selection
//Filter selection-2
//It need to happen in the Internal vs External tab
@Test
public void Filterselection_2() throws Exception{
Log.info("Clicking Internal Vs External tab");
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Internal vs External")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Visualization dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor3 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor3.executeScript("document.getElementById('visualizationId').style.display='block';");
Select select3 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("visualizationId")));
select3.selectByVisibleText("ICC");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on Type dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor02 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor02.executeScript("document.getElementById('classificationId').style.display='block';");
Select select02 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("classificationId")));
select02.selectByVisibleText("Internal PRs");
Thread.sleep(6000);
Log.info("Clicking on topography dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor4= (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor4.executeScript("document.getElementById('topographyId').style.display='block';");
Select select4 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("topographyId")));
select4.selectByVisibleText("ICC");
Thread.sleep(6000); 
Log.info("Clicking on Apply Filter button");
driver.findElement(By.id("kpiFilterSubmit")).click();
Thread.sleep(6000);
}
private boolean existsElement(String id) {
try {
driver.findElement(By.id(id));
} catch (Exception e) {
System.out.println("id is not present ");
return false;
}
return true;
}
private void waitforElement(WebDriver driver2, int i, String string) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
//@AfterMethod
@AfterTest
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
Log.info("Stopping Selenium...");
Log.info("______________________________________________________________"); 
driver.quit();
String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
Assert.fail(verificationErrorString);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Any one please help me for the scenario

Comment: Do u mean u need to run ...same set of tests for both the tabs???

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute ***dependsOnMethods***, of @Test, to sequentialize your tests. You can read further about the annotations in TestNG at - [TectNG Annotations](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations).

Comment: Yes. i want to run same set of test for both tabs but. 1st one tab need to complete then next tab need to run.

Comment: You can use simple for loop, after fetching all the WebElements which are tab. Another way could be using @dataprovider. **dataprovider** reads input from xls and executes all tests for each row in the xls. So you could provide each of your tabs as the row in dataprovider xls. If you go through the link I provided, I am sure you will find the solution which suits you best.

Answer (score 0):

So why don't you abstract those tests and than call it in your "Default" and "Internal vs External"? In you case I would use [Page Objects](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects)

Comment: Any once can help bye checking the above added code

Answer (score 0):

You can use Groups annotation in TestNG. Write all your required Test cases under Default tab, then add that test cases into one group as below

```
public class Test1 {
  @Test(groups = { "functest", "checkintest" })
  public void testMethod1() {
  }

  @Test(groups = {"functest", "checkintest"} )
  public void testMethod2() {
  }

  @Test(groups = { "functest" })
  public void testMethod3() {
  }
}
```

And it will execute that particular group test cases, then it will execute another once group test cases are completed.

**testng.xml**

```
<test name="Test1">
  <groups>
    <run>
      <include name="functest"/>
    </run>
  </groups>
  <classes>
    <class name="example1.Test1"/>
  </classes>
</test>
```